# Subtle difference in how HAML handles render method with block in Rails templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I stumbled across what looks to be an inconsistency in how HAML handles the `render` method in Rails.

*Example 1 in **ERB**:*

```
# template.html.erb
This is the index template.
<%= render :layout => 'form4', :partial => 'stuff2' %>

# _layout.html.erb
<%= form_tag do %>
    <div class="something">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
<% end %>

# _partial.html.erb
<b>meh</b>
<%= text_field_tag 'name' %>
```

*Example 1 in **HAML**:*

```
# template.html.haml
This is the index template.
=render :layout => 'form2', :partial => 'stuff1'

# _layout.html.haml
=form_tag do
    .something
        =yield

# _partial.html.haml
%b meh
=text_field_tag 'name'
```

As expected, both result in the same rendering (abbreviated below):

```
This is the index template.
<form>
    <div class="something"> 
        <b>meh</b> 
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" /> 
    </div> 
</form>
```

Now, **here's** where the weirdness kicks in. When I adjust the `render` statement to use the block syntax as below:

*In **ERB**:*

```
# template.html.erb
This is the index template.
<%= render :layout => 'form3' do %>
    <b>meh</b>
    <%= text_field_tag 'name' %>
<% end %>

# _layout.html.erb
<%= form_tag do %>
    <div class="something">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

*In **HAML**:*

```
# template.html.haml
This is the index template.
=render :layout => 'form1' do
    %b meh
    =text_field_tag 'name'

# _layout.html.haml
=form_tag do
    .something
        =yield
```

I get the same above rendering in the ERB version, but the HAML code outputs:

```
This is the index template.
<b>meh</b> 
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" /> 
<form>
    <div class='something'></div> 
</form>
```

It is as if HAML somehow isn't respecting the block that was passed to it. According to HAML's docs, they support blocks that autoclose based on indentation, so I don't suspect that is an issue. Also, in their docs, I saw a definition for a `render` method of their own. Could it be possible that it isn't implemented properly to accompany the same interface as rails's (erb's?) `render` method?

On that note, if this is truly an inconsistency in the methods interface, does it justify opening up an issue on HAML?

Just added an example app showing behavior at https://github.com/iamvery/haml-weirdness

It's also worth noting that I noticed this change when I upgraded my rails app to 3.0.9 and haml to 3.1.2. Leaving haml at 3.0.24 resulted in `Cannot modify SafeBuffer in place` error in rails 3.0.9...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I am having the same issue. It is also described at https://github.com/nex3/haml/issues/412
There is a issue_412 branch at nex3's github account but it is not complete. 
You could take a shot at fixing haml, I decided to go back to rails 3.0.7.

Comment: This looks to be fixed with HAML 3.1.3!